# Why am I *congratulated* after finishing the new profile form?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

When I arrived on SO today, I was requested to fill a form to update my profile. There were three questions, nothing big.

Yet when I finished it, I got a "*congratulations* you're all set" message.

Why abuse the term "congratulations"? I didn't achieve anything fantastic, difficult or that deserves praises. So why am I congratulated? Can't I just get a thanks or something like that? It's not like we're gonna open a bottle of champagne just because I answered three questions, is it?

Comment: Abuse the term "congratulations", how is that abuse?

Comment: Giving an extraordinary meaning to an ordinary action. That's some kind of abuse imo. The [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/congratulations) seems to go in my way. I did nothing big, nothing meaningful but got praise for it. I don't deserve this, so I shouldn't be congratulated. Therefore the word has been abused.

Comment: congratulations, I have no idea what's going on here

Comment: It's like when programming: the right tools at the right moment. Words are tools. Here, a tool has been misused.

Comment: all that fuss over "congratulations", really? From the wiki entry you linked, it says "Expressing praise and approval, expressing approbation." what if it was more meant as "approval" than "praise". I feel like we're crying over spilled milk...

Comment: Because you're special!

Comment: it's just a word...

Answer (score 14):

#### Thanks :)

[image: Salamat!]

It was our way of saying thank you, while letting you know that:

- It was something to accomplish, however trivial, and you did it.
- I don't even know what to say here, but I can't seem to leave a post with only one bullet point.

We really do put a lot of effort into copy that we show to users. I'm a little lost on how this is abusing the term - it wasn't our intent to trivialize anything. We promised it would be short, you agreed to do it and finished it, it just naturally felt like the correct thing to say.

I don't see an immediate compelling need to change anything, unless our use of the word could be considered offensive?

I could get equally irritated at something like "We love you for doing this!", but congratulations? I think that's pretty well in fair play.

Comment: Congratulations, you filled in a second bullet point despite having nothing to fill it with! (On a more serious note, I agree completely with this answer and also don't see how it can be an abuse of the term. The user accomplished something, congratulations is appropriate in my eyes.)

Comment: To answer your question, the usage of the word is not offensive. It's numbing though. Using it for trivial tasks makes the word less and less relevant the more it's used. As I see the huge backlash (9 downvotes on 30 views), it's probably me who should accept any kind of praise without question for whatever irrelevant task I perform.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I also feel strongly that certain words are broadly misappropriated in colloquial conversation, but I'm having quite a bit of difficulty empathizing with this one. When you say 'abused', you're implying quite deliberate malice, which I believe is the chief cause of the reaction you're seeing - nothing like that was intended. We really did want to congratulate folks that took the time to do what you did. Programmers are busy people and we _are genuinely thrilled_ when they take some time to help us.

Comment: Nope, I don't claim there's anything deliberate. If you felt so, I'm sorry. It's noteworthy that I'm not a native English speaker so the nuances in the words might be overstated in either SO's "congratulations" or my "abused". But the direct translations of "congratulations" into French on several websites all indicate something more than ordinary. The Wiktionary link seems to keep that meaning.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire We don't want to patronize people when we really mean to just say "Great, thanks for doing that!" - I will bring this up with our product team. I can't promise anything, but thank you for staying around and helping me understand what made you so upset.

Comment: @TimPost there's always the exceedingly neutral `<confirmation of user action completion>`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire  as another frenchie I can corroborate that "felicitations" is usually for quite an achievement. In English, it's not as strong (or I've never felt it as strog at least )

Comment: @Patrice Indeed. But why do you assume I'm French when only 1/3 of French-speaking people worldwide are French?

Comment: First you take issue with being congratulated, now you're taking issue with someone thinking you might be french because you speak french? Stop this.